# Automatic login to cisco anyconnect vpn on linux

Tags: cisco-vpn-client

Is there any way to get the vpn client to read in the username and password (I'm ok with plaintext for now) without having to type it everytime?

Edit: My intention is to call a script through ssh_config that will automatically connect to the vpn when I ssh a specific host.

This is the closest solution I've found: http://backdrift.org/automatic-vpn-login-on-connect-with-ssh-and-vpnc

Answer (score 0):

This is easily possible when going for the simpler solution of `NetworkManager`, there's a Cisco VPN plugin for it.

Comment: I added some context to the question.

Comment: Oh, vpnc, not anyconnect? Just specify `Xauth (username|password)` in the config.